# Exception in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, out-of-memory

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "ClientThread";

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-2-thread-1"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "http-nio-8080-Poller";

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Catalina-utility-2";

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "MaintenanceTimer-3-thread-1";

I have tried to visulize my threads using visulalvm tool and jdk mission control tool but unable to resolve it and tried multiple loggings in application but at end error comes rarely but can't figure it out.

Comment: It seems your application either has a memory leak or you've just assigned too little max memory for it to do its work. The exceptions won't tell you where most of the memory is needed, just what was the proverbial last drop that made the bucket spill. Since those exceptions seem to be rare you might want to configure your VM to create a heap dump on OOM - what VM are you using?

Comment: If you're using a Hotspot JVM, you could try adding `-XX:HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=[absolute path to dump location]`. Then grab those dumps and analyze them, e.g. with a tool like [Eclipse MAT](https://eclipse.dev/mat/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.